# BIM360 upload a file tutorial has broken link?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to follow the upload files tutorial but there is a broken link: (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-6-upload-the-file-to-the-storage-object) points to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT but that is not a valid page. Any idea what the correct page is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this to us. The correct URL is https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-PUT/

Next time, it would be nice if you feedback it by clicking the feedback button on the right side of the page. It will send the message to our documentation team directly.

BTW, sorry for forgetting this. We are migrating to the direct-s3 approach for uploading/downloading objects from the OSS buckets. Here are some related blog posts on this topic for your reference. Our SDK migration is still on the way. Once it's done, we will have another blog post announcement for that. Please bear with us.

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-nodejs-samples
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-net-samples

Meanwhile, we also asked our product team to update the tutorial with this direct-s3 approach. Hope it would be delivered soon.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I did submit the feedback as well, but wasn't sure how quick that would be attended to; or if anyone else already knew the correct link, I didn't want to limit my options.

Comment: I assume it's you who gave me the "-1" for asking this question? Even though AutoDesk relies HIGHLY on members of the public to ask and answer questions? (As I said, I did indeed report the issue via the feedback button, but I am still waiting for a reply by that avenue. Hmm...)

Comment: no, I didn't do that. I replied to you and did the same thing I just advised. Maybe some guys from worldwide who was asked by Stackoverflow to review questions and is not from Forge Help team.

Comment: You can see the activity log of this thread here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72005091/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries As you can see the "-1" vote was made 2 days two right you send this question. I replied to you yesterday.

Comment: I updated my answer above. Sorry for missing that. We will have a big change in uploading/downloading files to the Forge OSS bucket.

Comment: Eason, thanks for the update on S3; with any luck that is a tad easier than the current method, I will give that a look. [Regarding the soon-to-be-obsolete process, I have been stuck on the step right before this, the "create storage location" step (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/storage) Using the curl example (with appropriate subs) gives me a json error at position 0.]

Comment: Hi David, could you try other tools like Postman? Here is my Postman scripts https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman, and you should find the storage one under `BIM360 > Data Management API > Storage`.

Comment: I found the issue, I had not set ("Accept", "application/json"). Out of all the API calls I am already making, this is the only one that complained.